# VLAN help on ESX 4/vSphere

Tags: vmware-esx

I setup a new VLAN with ID 153 in vSphere for my ESX4 server. The VLAN is setup for virtual machines and then I added a new NIC to the VM I want to be able to access the VM. The NIC is added to VLAN 153, but yet I am unable to ping the VLAN .1 IP that is setup on our Cisco 3750.

The IP is properly setup on the Cisco 3750 because I'm able to ping the interface IP from other machines on the network. I'm guessing there must be an issue with the cabling.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say the NIC is added to VLAN 153, do you mean the VM NIC is set up that way, or the virtual switch in the ESX?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have an active dot1q trunk to your 3750 and that the vlan is not being pruned off, either on the server or the switch.  Also ensure that your vlan is up/up and that the switch can ping its own .1 interface.

Comment: and if you wish to route BETWEEN vlans you need to make sure some basic statements are in the switch like "ip routing" at least, at one point you had to do that.